# Legality of using images of celebrities on a website

Tags: copyright, legal

I'm planning on making a website about celebrities and on the website there will be images of celebrities. I know that you can't use images of celebrities owned by other people (I hope you understand what I mean).

How would I go about getting images of celebrities and using them on my website for free? Because I've checked the prices of images and they are crazy high, like 200 Euro per picture, and I don't have that kind of money as I'm a teenager finishing school and I need to save up for college.

I've attached an image down below. How do I tell if I'm allowed to use it on my website or not. And if not, how do I find images of celebrities that I'm allowed to use?

What if I use the image on my website but only make the money from adsense; would that be allowed?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**No**, that would not be allowed. You're using photos that are owned by other people. Using them without permission is unnacceptable, ***especially*** if you're planning on making money from that which you're using the pictures for, even if it's from "another source" like ads.

I don't know of any repository of celebrity images that allow the photos to be used for free or know why one would even exist, as it's a lot of people's source of revenue.

Comment: what if i make the website as pinterest did what i mean by that is that when the person clicks on the image of the celebrity it opens a new tab to where i got the image from? i doubt pinterest buys all the images i think they just give them credit and thats it is it?

Comment: Pinterest puts the legality of images uploaded on the users themselves. If a company or photographer requests that their photo be taken down because whoever posted it didn't have the right to post it, Pinterest complies and takes it down. You, as the site owner, posting other people's pictures without permission and making money from it are liable to get sued, or at least have to take your site down, for not getting proper permissions for the images

Answer (score 0):

Look for images that are licensed under a "Creative Commons" license.  These are images where the photographer has granted users a license to use the images for free, but with specific guidelines.

If you google "Finding images with creative commons license" you should find a number of resources that will allow you to find usable images. How many of them will be of celebrities, I couldn't tell you.

You also have to make sure to comply with the specifics of the Creative Commons license, which may say the images can only be used for non-commercial purposes, or cannot be changed at all, or you must give credit to the photographer, etc.